# Damped track hair - Cycles vs Eveee

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I created hair with damped track on armatures to "simulate" physics when head to which is hair connected with childOf. When I use Evee armatures with damped track are moving smoothly however when I change to Cycles it is shaky. What can be problem?

In viewport everything is OK
Here is video of Cycles (problematic one): https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7gobfqpo11eepts2ud1jq/testcycles0001-0049.mp4?rlkey=1isr06vn7a4n666l3qnvt1g25&dl=0

Here is video of Evee: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8xlcjnt3x5ph0lg2vl0eb/testevee0001-0049.mp4?rlkey=m77fnafb3d5cx7dbxoz6reetp&dl=0